# How to keep same image heights in fluid CSS grids?

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-grid

I'm quite new to css grids. I need to code a 2 columns component, with fluid equal height images inside. I could do it with flexbox, but this time I need a css grid, and it must be responsive.

That said, this component has 2 images, 1 per column. The original img files have equal heights (340x300, 708x300). I need to show them about 30% and 70% width, minus gap. I tried to use both 'auto' and fr units, also combined, but no luck.

On the last/large breakpoint, it's all fine:

[image]

The problem comes when on smaller breakpoints: I can't keep the 2 images the same exact height (make them scale with same height):

[image]

Here's some code, one of the versions. But any variation of this code (different unit combinations) give some kind of problems, and none of them makes me having equal height images:

```
.images-block-box{

  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  //grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  //grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  //grid-template-columns: 33.333% 66.666%;
}
```

Ah, and obviously, the images are fluid (`max-width:100%; height: auto`).

How to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The original img files have equal heights (340x300, 708x300).

You can exploit the fact that *fractional units* work in *proportions* of the items. So use `grid-template-columns: 340fr 708fr` *if the images file are not going to change*. See demo below:

```css
.images-block-box{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: 340fr 708fr;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-block-box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/340x300"/>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/708x300"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer. The trick is using `img{object-fit: cover;}`

```css
.wrap{
  width:100vw;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:3fr 7fr;
  grid-gap:1em;
}
.a img{width:100%;height:100%;object-fit: cover;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="a">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/340x300" />
 </div> 
 <div class="a">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/708x300" />
 </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for a cross-browser solution. Microsoft was not aware of this standard when they built IE11. As usual.